# Why is nearly all the bottleneck in my Managed application External Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I wrote a tool that reduces the number of a cubes in a voxel world by combing them into larger cubes. It's entirely a managed application, written in C#, and pretty much just does a ton of searching in several `HashSet`. For what it does, I think its performance is reasonable, but the Visual Studio 2015 RC profiler isn't helping me assess that.

[image]

As you can see from the image above, 80% of the time is spent in "[External Code]". And it doesn't seem to make a difference whether *Just My Code* is enabled or disabled each time I run the profiler. As I highly doubt it's spending 80% of the time doing garbage collection, I'm wondering if this might be a bug with the profiler.

Comment: There are plenty of examples in purely managed code where the framework executes external code. Take a look at `System.String` - it's full of them. So your profiler could be recording a lot of those types of calls.

Comment: @Enigmativity Most of GDI & WinForms too, but IIRC Dictionary and List have purely managed implementations (I've seen them), and I would doubt that HashSet was any different.

Answer (score 1):

In the project settings under build, turn on debugging of native and external code.  When you run the profiler, you will be prompted to download pdb symbol files.  Do so.  This will give you some (but not all) visibility into the external code being run.  The only limitation is that you will still not have the source code for the external code.

You said your application mostly searches in several hashsets.  Have you considered that most time is spent in the hashset implementation?